# Crash with WebKit::WebProcessPool::networkProcessCrashed EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

Getting this random crash when using WKWebview. Please let me know how to find out the reason or ideas how to fix it.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000

    Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  WebKit                         0x18ec33120 WebKit::WebProcessPool::networkProcessCrashed(WebKit::NetworkProcessProxy&) + 80
1  WebKit                         0x18ecf2b70 WebKit::NetworkProcessProxy::didFinishLaunching(WebKit::ProcessLauncher*, IPC::Connection::Identifier) + 232
2  WebKit                         0x18e9730e8 WebKit::ProcessLauncher::didFinishLaunchingProcess(int, IPC::Connection::Identifier) + 124
3  WebKit                         0x18ebeba44 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WebKit::ProcessLauncher::launchProcess()::$_1::operator()(NSObject<OS_xpc_object>*)::'lambda'(), void>::call() + 132
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x18c7859cc WTF::RunLoop::performWork() + 528
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x18c786518 WTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*) + 32
6  CoreFoundation                 0x182c01bf0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
7  CoreFoundation                 0x182c01af0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 204
8  CoreFoundation                 0x182c00e9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 356
9  CoreFoundation                 0x182bfb3e0 __CFRunLoopRun + 776
10 CoreFoundation                 0x182bfaba0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
11 GraphicsServices               0x199938598 GSEventRunModal + 160
12 UIKitCore                      0x1854ea3d8 -[UIApplication _run] + 1052
13 UIKitCore                      0x1854ef958 UIApplicationMain + 164
```

Comment: Probably you are doing something on the background thread and then you update your UI without moving back to the main using DispatchQueue.main.async { }. it is difficult to say if you don’t show your code

Comment: Thank you. But, it actually crashes on the main thread. It is just a normal webview that looks like crashes sometimes on app launch after the Splash view.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: No, sorry cannot post due to privacy